# React.js shouldComponentUpdate() and react-router Link

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I currently have a doubt about the correct combined implementation of **react-router Link navigation** and **shouldComponentUpdate()** on the root application level.

That is, I have a root component called **App.jsx** which contains a global component with a *header, footer, sidebar* etc and this same component has an *ajax long-poll* which retrieves new registrations in the system and updates the state when new users register.

Since I don't want to push a re-render to the component *(and therefore all it's children)* on ajax responses that don't have updates I decided to make use of the lovely **shouldComponentUpdate()** method.

So, I came up with something like this - noting that I'm making use of lo-dash:

```
shouldComponentUpdate (/*prevProps*/, prevState) {
  return !_.isEqual(this.state,prevState);
}
```

With this the component correctly ignores irrelevant responses about the latest registrations.

Now, the problem appears when I have to make the routing. To clarify before, this is the kind of structure of the **render()**:

*Note: the _routerTransitionKey is just a helper I have to not make transitions when I'm navigating internal views state and it's working correctly.*

```
<Grid key='app' id="wrapper" className="no-padding">
  <Header user={this.state.user} allRegistrations={this.state.allRegistrations}/>
  <section id="page-wrapper">
    <NotificationArea key='internalNotification' />
    <RouteHandler key={_routerTransitionKey} user={this.state.user} allRegistrations={this.state.allRegistrations}/>
  </section>
</Grid>
```

Because I have the RouteHandler inside this global component, I have the issue that a change in the route is completely ignored by it, **since the application state itself didn't change**. That causes the component to never trigger the **render()** on navigation and therefore *never update the RouteHandler*.

What I needed would be something like:

```
 shouldComponentUpdate (/*prevProps*/, prevState) {
   return !_.isEqual(this.state,prevState) || ROUTE_CHANGED ;
 }
```

My question is: does anybody out there knows of a clever approach to this issue? I'm trying to avoid having to create yet another wrapping component to handle the Routes before they reach this App component I currently have...

Comment: any reason you are ignoring props in the shouldComponentUpdate() ? React router injects the current path into [routehandler props](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/master/doc/03%20Components/Route%20Handler.md), so they would change. (Is your app.jsx a routehandler too?)

Comment: Hey @WayneC, I was trying your suggestion now and apparently the react-router props are not injected into the react props at this stage. That means it's not possible to use that to compare the previous and next paths. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Answer (score 0):

So, after the tip from @WayneC, even though the react-router doesn't inject the props directly into the react component props, there's a possible way inspired by that approach.

I achieved what I wanted by doing a slight change using not the **this.props**, but instead the **this.context.router.getCurrentPath()**

So now the solution looks like this:

```
shouldComponentUpdate (/*nextProps*/, nextState) {
  return !_.isEqual(this.state,nextState) || this.context.router.getCurrentPath() !== _routerTransitionKey;
}
```

Just to make it clearer, my _routerTransitionKey gets its value from an imported Util that looks mostly like this:

```
var Utils = {
  Router: {
    TransitionKey: {
      get: function(){
        return Router.HistoryLocation.getCurrentPath();
      }
    }
  }
}

_routerTransitionKey = Utils.Router.TransitionKey.get();
```

This `_routerTransitionKey` is scoped in an upper level, and I modify it on every **render()**, so that I keep track of it for later comparison.

And... that's it.

Comment: This is using lodash?